# When is Breq's ability to see through her crew's eyes first mentioned?

Tags: imperial-radch, ancillary-sword

In Chapter 5 of [*Ancillary Sword*](https://www.annleckie.com/novel/ancillary-sword/), Breq mentions being able to see “through Kalr Five’s unsuspecting eyes”. Is this the first place in the Imperial Radch trilogy that her ability to do this is mentioned? Up to that point I had assumed that all the data Ship was able to provide was acquired through sensors on Ship itself, and from sensors (in the real real world sense of physiological or biometric sensors) either worn or implanted (which it is doesn't matter, at least up to this point in the books), rather than something as all encompassing and sophisticated as an ability to actually *see through a human crew member's own eyes*.

Did I read this right. Can Breq actually see through the eyes of her crew? If so, is this the first place in the trilogy that this ability is mentioned?